# How to run a qt android app on secondary/exernal screen

Tags: android, qt

I have developed a Qt app which I've cross-compiled for android app and want to run as an android app. 
But I wish to run this app on the secondary screen connected to my android board, while the android screen runs on the primary display.

Should this be achieved from Qt or is it to do on the Android framework? 
Do I have any chance to tweak my Qt android app java files for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how well the android plugin supports multiple screens, seeing how 99.99% of android devices are stuck at one. You can check via `QGuiApplication::screens()` to see if they are detected.

Comment: Qt basically runs it's GUI inside a normal activity. So as long as you can get the activity to be shown on the second screen with java methods only, it should work for Qt as well. Just create a custom activity and let it extend the Qt activity to get started

Comment: @dtech: Thanks for suggestion.I had checked QGuiApplication::screens() to see no. of screen and it displays the external display as virtual display with primary display as false. How can we change the primary display? Also since Qt will be an apk on android, I'm not sure if it would work irrespective how android framework is configured. Thanks.

Comment: @Felix: Yes, I read there's a QtActivityDelegate which helps Qt to draw UI on a surface view. While going through all gen files, I found few activity java flies. One of them which is the main activity for the Qt app , I tried to add presentation api mode there, but it needs an instance of view/layout to display on secondary/presentation mode. I'm unable to find this that how Qt UI is really drawn on the app. Or where is the Layout/view in android framework created for Qt app so that Qt shall be able to render it's UI. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you should not edit generated files. Copy them to your project instead using the "create templates" button as seen [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-deploying-android.html#specifying-settings-for-packages). But for the rest I can't say anything.